# Geometry Nodes: How to make chain reaction or chain explosion

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to make this, but with **randomly** generated points for each ball. This should be in 3D and the circles should be balls. The values could either be hand-animated or from scene time.

It is surprisingly difficult, my tests didn't yield very presentable results :(

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Starts with a single seed point and then "explodes" the points by generating a number of child particles in several stages. Each particle has a randomized lifetime. The output of each stage consists of alive and dead particles. The dead particles are then exploded in the next stage, and discarded after the final stage.
[image]

To explode a set of points, first a number of child particles is generated. Then a bunch of attributes need to be initialized:

- lifetime and start_time are needed to determine when the particle dies and explodes itself.
- start_position and velocity are needed for animation
- level can be used to distinguish different particle stages later on
- ID is generated to give each particle a consistent unique value for randomization. Just using the plain Index would not work because adding and removing particles changes the index.
- A custom seed should be used for each stage.
  [image]

Finally particles are animated very simply with linear movement. The node group also separates out dead particles for further explosion or discarding.[image]

After generating all the points we can then do the usual instancing. Play with the named attributes: use the different levels, animate over lifetime, etc.
[image]